# How to add a linebreak (<br>) to my onclick="('', '')

Tags: javascript, html, line-breaks

I'm trying to write out a p in my onclick=('','') with linebreaks, but br wont work.

I want to be able to do this:

'hi 
how are you doing?'

Html:

```
<area shape="circle" coords="200,38,28" onclick="MapPopUp('Example','hi how are you doing')" alt="">

<div id="popUp" class="hidden">
            <h3 id="popUpHeader"></h3>
            <p id="popUpContent"></p>
            <div>
                <a onclick="CloseMapPopUp();">
                    <img id="close" src="images/close.png" alt="close button">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
function MapPopUp(header, content) {
    PopUpDiv.classList.remove("hidden");
    PopUpHeader.innerHTML = header;
    PopUpContent.innerHTML = content;
}

function CloseMapPopUp() {
    PopUpDiv.classList.add("hidden");
    PopUpHeader.innerHTML = "";
    PopUpContent.innerHTML = "";
}

var PopUpDiv = document.getElementById("popUp");
var PopUpHeader = document.getElementById("popUpHeader");
var PopUpContent = document.getElementById("popUpContent");
```

I hope someone out there can help 
In advance thanks for your help!!!

Comment: innerHtml creates just a text string with '<br />' inside?

Comment: You should add a dom element, instead of a string, i think

Comment: You can also try \n or \n\r instead of the <br />

Answer (score 0):

Might be untidy but would work.

using an escape character

```
onclick="MapPopUp('Example','hi \n\r how are you doing')"
```

and your MapPopUp function can look something like this.

```
   function MapPopUp(header, content) {
      PopUpDiv.classList.remove('hidden');
      PopUpHeader.innerHTML = header;
      let contentHtml = '';
      content.split('\n\r').forEach(c => {
        contentHtml += `<p>${c.trim()}</p>`;
      });
      PopUpContent.innerHTML = contentHtml;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    div= document.getElementById("popUp");
    br = document.createElement("br");
    div.appendChild(br);
```